# Is there a way to abort destroy and update a record when chain halts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to use 'paranoid mode' when I destroy a record on Rails 5. 
But when I call :abort in the before_destroy callback. It halts the chain (obviously), but not update the record (deleted_at). It shows in the console the update of that record (setting deleted_at DateTime, but then Rails call rollback of the transaction.

Anyone know what could be?

Regards and happy new year!